# How can I exclude a product from a promotion code

Tags: magento-1.9, magento1.9.3

I'm running Magento version 1.9.3.6. I have created a promotion code to offer a 10% discount. There are 2 products that I would like to exclude from this promotion code. How can I do that?

I couldn't find any solution for this issue.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can add condition in your promotion Rule like

**SKU is not 'ABC', 'XYZ'**

so that promotion will not apply on that 2 products.

For Example,
http://www.screencast.com/t/3BNVXiDbu

Comment: Also, if they are in the same category you can exclude that or you can create an attribute and apply it to both products and exclude based on that attribute. These methods are scalable if there are mulitiple products to be exluded and you don't have top select each product individually.

Comment: The issue is that I don't get the options that you show in your example. If I go to Actions (or conditions), then add a condition, then I get this Attribute is assigned // or Attribute is not assigned.